# Making A 3rd Party Auth With Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

What I am trying to do is allow users of my firebase application to authenticate in say Streamlabs but I don’t really know if that’s possible with firebase. Can someone provide me with a starting point or where to look?

Comment: That'll require that you convert the Streamlabs auth information to a custom token, and then use that to sign in to Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens. Examples: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/okta-auth or https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/username-password-auth

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just realized I set the dupe to the question you answered.